# Some details in the proof to show that a reciprocal function is continuous.

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity, proof-explanation

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous. Let $Y=\{x\in X:f(x)\neq0\}$. Prove in detail that the function $g:Y\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$ is continuous.

Proof:

Fix $x\in Y$. Let $f(x)=r>0$ (the proof is similar for $r<0$). Using the continuity of $f$, we find a $\delta>0$ such that $f(B_{\delta}(x))\subset B_{r/2}(f(x))$. Thus for any $y\in Y$ with $d(x,y)<\delta$ we have $|f(x)-f(y)|<r/2$, which is to say

$$0<r/2\leq f(x)-r/2<f(y)<f(x)+r/2.$$

Thus for all such $y$ we have $f(y)>r/2$ and so $\frac{1}{f(y)}<2/r$. Now let $\epsilon>0$ and choose $\delta'>0$ so that $f(B_{\delta'}(x))\subset B_{\epsilon r^2/2}(f(x))$. Set $\delta''=\min\{\delta,\delta'\}$.

Then for $y\in X$ with $d(y,x)<\delta''$ we have

$$|g(y)-g(x)|=\left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{f(y)f(x)}\right|<\frac{2}{r^2}|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon.$$

Hence $f(B_{\delta''}(x))\subset B_{\epsilon}(g(x))$, and so $g$ is continuous at $x\in Y$. Since $x\in Y$ was arbitrary, $g$ is continuous.

**There are two parts that I don't quite understand:**

1. Choose $\delta'>0$ so that $f(B_{\delta'}(x))\subset B_{\epsilon r^2/2}(f(x))$. Why is the radius of the ball for $f(x)$ is $\epsilon r^2/2$?
2. Where does the $\frac{2}{r^2}$ in $\frac{2}{r^2}|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ come from?

Can anybody please explain that? Helps are much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. We choose this radius so that $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$ (which we use at the end of the proof).
2. We already have that $\frac{1}{f(y)}<2/r$ and that $f(x) = r$, so
   $$
   \frac{1}{f(y)f(x)} < \frac{2}{r} \cdot \frac{1}{r} = \frac{2}{r^2}.
   $$
   This is why we can say
   $$
   \left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{f(y)f(x)}\right|<\frac{2}{r^2}|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon.
   $$

Answer (score 0):

Quick question - why can we use algebra here when we don't know which metric we are supposed to be using? Surely we can only use the 3 properties of metrics, and not assume we are using the Euclidian distance?